# LEFT Join Query failure

Tags: sql, sqlite

Wondering if someone could explain why my query is not giving the desired result in SQLite

I have two tables

Table A contains many lines with a column called picklist_id in which the value is repeated, I am trying to get the distinct value of these and then check to see if this picklist id exists in table two. This is what I have but I am just getting an empty result

```
SELECT distinct(pt.picklist_id) from picklisttable pt LEFT JOIN pickingtable p on 
pt.picklist_id = p.picklist_id where p.picklist_id = null
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? I want the picklist_id from table a returned if it does not exist in table b

Comment: You can't left join using packlist_id and then ask it to be null.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My original query had a distinct wrapper around pt.picklist_id, i removed it for testing and forgot to add it in again before posting this, I will edit my q now

Comment: @Bob - so how would you suggest I do it? This is about as far as my sql knowledge extends!

Comment: @dave . . . Bob is simply wrong.  You are doing this the right way.

Comment: I guess I really don't get what's going on here then. I have a background in Oracle, and if I select distinct column A and left outer join another table using column A, then in the where clause I specify that column A is null, than you are only going to get null as your result.

Comment: Oh, nevermind - The column in the where clause is from the table in the outer join - sorry - it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be IS NULL, not = NULL.

```
SELECT pt.picklist_id 
FROM picklisttable pt 
LEFT JOIN pickingtable p on pt.picklist_id = p.picklist_id 
WHERE p.picklist_id = null;
```

When asking for the existence of data, the EXISTS clause is more readable usually, or the IN clause when dealing with one column only.

```
SELECT pt.picklist_id 
FROM picklisttable pt 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from pickingtable p where pt.picklist_id = p.picklist_id);
```

or

```
SELECT pt.picklist_id 
FROM picklisttable pt 
WHERE pt.picklist_id NOT IN (select p.picklist_id from pickingtable p);
```

Or deal with sets and use EXCEPT, which I consider even more readable:

```
SELECT picklist_id FROM picklisttable
EXCEPT
SELECT picklist_id FROM pickingtable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Same query except instead of `= NULL` it's `IS NULL`

```
SELECT distinct(pt.picklist_id) from picklisttable pt LEFT JOIN pickingtable p on 
pt.picklist_id = p.picklist_id where p.picklist_id IS null
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 your answer but will mark @thorsten as correct for completeness and providing other options

Answer (score 0):

For your where clause, try "p.picklist_id is null" instead of "p.picklist_id = null"